# How to solve this error, The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: laravel

I'm having a problem with this?
How to solve this error: `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.`

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('term-one.store')}}">
    @csrf
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror"
                   value="{{ old('name') }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="grade" value="{{$grade->id}}"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="{{$subject->id}}"/>
            @error('name')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-right">
        <div class="col-md-12 mt-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'name' => 'required|min:3|max:150',
        'grade' =>'required',
        'subject' => 'required'
    ]);
    
    dd($request);
}
```

I dont know what am I doing wrong?I dont know what am I doing wrong? I dont know what am I doing wrong?

php artisan route:list

```
| POST   | term-one                  | term-one.store     | App\Http\Controllers\TermOneController@store                           | web                                                                         |
|        | GET|HEAD  | term-one                      | term-one.index     | App\Http\Controllers\TermOneController@index                           | web                                                                         |
|        | GET|HEAD  | term-one/create               | term-one.create    | App\Http\Controllers\TermOneController@create                          | web                                                                         |
|        | PUT|PATCH | term-one/{term_one}           | term-one.update    | App\Http\Controllers\TermOneController@update                          | web                                                                         |
|        | GET|HEAD  | term-one/{term_one}           | term-one.show      | App\Http\Controllers\TermOneController@show                            | web                                                                         |
|        | DELETE    | term-one/{term_one}           | term-one.destroy   | App\Http\Controllers\TermOneController@destroy                         | web                                                                         |
|        | GET|HEAD  | term-one/{term_one}/edit      | term-one.edit      | App\Http\Controllers\TermOneController@edit                            | web                                                                         |
```

Route File

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the route list?

Comment: I have share it above

Comment: I too cannot see anything wrong with the shared code, maybe someone else might notice. But lets try this in the meant time: check the url that gets registered in the network tab (browser inspect element) when you click on the submit button.

Comment: Try with `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: not working....

Comment: @Vusumzi You getting this error after click the submit button?

Comment: Yes, after I click the submit button

Comment: could you please share the route file

Comment: @MustafaGoda Shared the file

Comment: please edit route "termone" to "term-one" in the route